# Tool/Method that converts activity XAML(X) files from WF 4 to 4.5

Tags: xaml, workflow-foundation, xamlx

When opening a VS2010 project XAML file in VS 2012, you get: "activity could not be loaded because of errors in the xaml"

Has anyone found a way of handling the subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By switching the project from .NET 4 to 4.5, I am now able to view the XAML activity workflow